# What exactly does the ornamental design for a dual-action vibrator entail?

Tags: design-patent, usd653349, design-medical

Is this for the outside shape?  The mixture of materials?  Please describe in detail what this [design patent](http://www.google.com/patents/USD653349) actually means.

Answer (score 2):

To quote Judge Rader (of the Court of Appeals for the Federal Circuit), with a design paternt: "you get the picture".  In other words, trying to describe it is generally pointless -- it's mostly about comparing the accused device to the picture(s) in the patent, and infringing basically means they look essentially the same.